# IE8- Gradient and Background image in the same filter is not working?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying to add a background image to a button, which already has gradient. But it appears to be not working.

Here is my CSS:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4c4c4c', 
endColorstr='#131313',GradientType=0), 
progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src="./media/images/mail.png");
```

I have also tried with `-ms-filter` but did not work.

This issue is only with IE8.

Comment: Does using either one on it's own work?

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does not support multiple backgrounds natively.

You might try a polyfill [**CSSPie**](http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if even using PIE you can mix images and gradients on an image.

An easier solution would be to have the button use the gradient and you could add a `<span>` element inside the button which would have as a background your png image.

Also, you could write your CSS such that only IE8 is targeted to show and load an image within the `<span>`.